# How can I configure Microsoft Account identity provider in Azure AD B2C to redirect to my URL

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-b2c, .net-core-authorization

I'm trying to set up web app authentication using active directory B2C, but when I use Microsoft Account identity provider (or any other except mail) in Azure callback URL is set to "https://(domain).b2clogin.com/(domain).onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp" and I cannot change it. 
Can you please help me what should I do to get a response with a token to my page which is on a different domain?[image]

Comment: you want to change ti to waht ?url will always be `https://(domain)b2clogin.com/(domain).onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp` or `https://login.onmicrosoft.com/(domain).onmicrosoft.comoauth2/authresp`

Comment: @Thomas I thought so, it means I need to implement this endpoint? My problem is that I'm developing API and I would like to test the authentication by redirecting the user to https://jwt.ms/ after login and use the token for testing. But I cannot do it. It works only for email authentication.
Also, what if my front end application won't be hosted on Azure? How I will get to the token?
Thank you for your response, I spent a huge amount of time on this.

Comment: From B2C you can create an application that redirect to `jwt.ms`. It does not matter where your application is hosted, only the redirect url matter

Comment: So I have to create an application which the only purpose will be to redirect the redirect from B2C? I knew there is this possibility, but it seems to be very inefficient. Do you know if there is any reason why Azure doesn't allow to change redirect URL? I think it was allowed in past Azure versions.

Comment: @MichalKalous If my answer is helpful, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the callback URL since it is used for auth response by design.
[image]

However, when you click **run user flow**, you will need to provide the B2C application(Under Azure AD B2C) and reply url(**This is the url which you can identify**).

[image]

After sign in, you will redirect to the url you configured before.

[image]